# MacOS Monterey - PHP extension GD is not loaded

Tags: php, macos, gd, nette

On MacOS (Monterey) I switched PHP version to 8.0. With MAMP 6.3 (not PRO).
In my source code (PHP, Nette), when I want to work with Image library, I get error "PHP extension GD is not loaded".
Its true, in my php.ini (in MAMP directory) isn`t any row with "extension=gd".

In older version PHP, the GD extension works. I can see in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/include/php/ext/gd folder. But in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.0/include/php/ext isn`t any "gd" folder. Why?

I tried to install some extension with PECL, but it wasn`t helpful.

Homebrew was updated to latest PHP at the beginning.

Thanks for advice!

---

EDIT:

I tried run `brew install gd` or reinstall, nothing works (command finish with success).

Even when I run `php -m` I can see module "gd". But still there si PHP warning with not loaded extension GD

Comment: If you see gd in `php -m` and `php -v` is php 8.0, then you have gd installed correctly for the CLI. Restarting your web service would probably fix this.

Comment: If you haven't already, refer to this guide: https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/FAQ/PHP/Install-a-PHP-extension-using-PECL/